Calculate $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (1-\alpha) \alpha^nP^{*n}(x)$
$$
\mbox{Let}\quad
P'(x)=\sum_{j=1}^n a_j\frac{a^jx^{j-1}}{(j-1)!}e^{-ax},x\geq 0
$$
be the density function of a mixture of Erlangs and let $\alpha\in(0,1)$:

Is is possible to determine an analytic expression for $$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1-\alpha) \alpha^nP^{*n}(x)$$
where $P^{*n}$ is the $n-$fold convolution of $P$ with itself and $P^{*0}(x)=0$?.
I was thinking about calculating
$\mathcal L^{-1}([\mathcal L(P)]^n)$, where $\mathcal L$ is the Laplace transform, but this looks really hard.


Given $\mathcal{L}\lbrace P_n'(t)\rbrace=s\mathcal{P}n(s)-\lim{t\rightarrow0^-}f(t)=\sum_{j=1}^na_j\frac{a^j}{{(s+a)}^j}$ where $\mathcal{P}_n(s)=\mathcal{L}\lbrace P_n(t)\rbrace$, I reckon the original problem may have a closed form (albeit still quite hairy) solution. Of course, you could still plug in $x\leftarrow t$ and integrate both sides with respect to $t$ on the interval $x\in(0,x)$, although that is making things unnecessarily more complicated in my opinion. Edit: What you notated as $P(t)$ I chose to write as $P_n(t)$ given the use of the index $n$ in the RHS.

I forgot to replace $f$ with $P_n$ but the formula is otherwise the same.

Also, though unrelated to my previous comments, the $n$-fold convolution of $P_n$ with itself is trivial given $P^{*0}=0$ as such would imply that $P_n^{*n}=P_n^{*n}*P_n^{*0}=P_n^{*n}*0=0$. Perhaps you meant to write $P_n^{*0}(0)=0$.

Obviously, $P\sim Exp(a)$ for $n=1$. This case is covered by Example 2.1 in https://www.kent.ac.uk/smsas/personal/lb209/files/risk-notes-10.pdf

The following paper gives the PDF of convolution of Erlangs. You might be able to deploy the fact, that the Erlangs in your mixture of Erlangs share the same parameter $a$. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/dema-2003-0125/pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiIg4mTramGAxWaX_EDHa4FCEoQFnoECBcQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3_rX3dX871doCAQNTuXknN

That $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\},P_n\in C^1[0,\infty)$ (more empirically, that $P_n'(x)$ exists for all positive-integral $n$ for $x\geq0$) implies that $P_n(x)$ is differentiable (and hence continuous) at $x=0$. Hence, $P_n(0)=\lim_{t\rightarrow0^-}P_n(t)$. Suppose $P_n(x)+C=\int P_n'(x)\mathrm{d}x$ for all $x\geq0$. Using dominated convergence, one may take the integral of the sum to be the sum of the integrals like so:
\begin{align}
P_n(x)+C&=\int P_n'(x)\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int\sum_{j=1}^na_j\frac{a^jx^{j-1}}{(j-1)!}e^{-ax}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^na_j\frac{a^j}{(j-1)!}\int x^{j-1}e^{-ax}\mathrm{d}x\\
\end{align}
Taking $x\leftarrow0$, one obtains the following:
\begin{align}
P_n(0)+C&=\sum_{j=1}^na_j\frac{a^j}{(j-1)!}\left(-\frac{(j-1)!}{a^j}+C_j\right)\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^n\left(a_j\frac{a^j}{(j-1)!}C_j-1\right)\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^na_j\frac{a^j}{(j-1)!}C_j-n
\end{align}
Though subtracting the arbitrary constant $C$ from both sides of the equation yields a new constant which one may call $C_0$ on the RHS, suppose the entirety of the RHS "agglutinates" into one $C_n$ (i.e. $P_n(0)=C_n$). Hence, Laplace transforming both sides of the equation for $P_n'(x)$ (where $x\leftarrow t$) yields the following result:
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}\{P_n'(t)\}&=\mathcal{L}\left\{\sum_{j=1}^na_j\frac{a^jt^{j-1}}{(j-1)!}e^{-at}\right\}\\
s\mathcal{P}_n(s)-\lim_{t\rightarrow0^-}P_n(t)&=\sum_{j=1}^na_j\frac{a^j}{(j-1)!}\mathcal{L}\left\{t^{j-1}e^{-at}\right\}\\
s\mathcal{P}_n(s)-P_n(0)&=\sum_{j=1}^na_j\frac{a^j}{(j-1)!}\left(\frac{(j-1)!}{{(s+a)}^j}\right)\\
s\mathcal{P}_n(s)-C_n&=\sum_{j=1}^na_j\frac{a^j}{{(s+a)}^j}\\
s\mathcal{P}_n(s)&=C_n+\sum_{j=1}^na_j\frac{a^j}{{(s+a)}^j}\\
\mathcal{P}_n(s)&=\frac{C_n}{s}+\sum_{j=1}^na_j\frac{a^j}{s{(s+a)}^j}\\
\end{align}
Note that, in the above, $\mathcal{L}\{P_n(t)\}=\mathcal{P}_n(s)$. In conjunction, let $f^{*0}=\delta$ and $\forall n\in\mathbb{N},f^{*n}=f^{*n-1}*f$ for all $f\in C^1[0,\infty)$. From this, $\mathcal{L}\{f^{*n}(t)\}={F(s)}^n$. Hence,
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}\left\{\sum_{n=0}^\infty(1-\alpha)\alpha^nP_n^{*n}(t)\right\}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(1-\alpha)\alpha^n\mathcal{L}\{P_n^{*n}(t)\}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(1-\alpha)\alpha^n{\mathcal{P}_n(s)}^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(1-\alpha){(\alpha\mathcal{P}_n(s))}^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(1-\alpha)\left(\alpha\frac{C_n}{s}+\alpha\sum_{j=1}^na_j\frac{a^j}{s{(s+a)}^j}\right)^n\\
\end{align}
Though the above series appears daunting, note that, at each iteration of the running index $n$, the summand is a rational function $\frac{A}{B}$ where $A,B\in\mathbb{R}[s]$ and $B\neq0$ for real $a_j$ and $a^j$. Hence, given the linearity of the $\mathcal{L}^{-1}$ operator, one could apply the inverse Laplace transform and use partial fraction decomposition on each successive term of the outer sum in order to obtain the equivalent term expressed in terms of a function on the time domain (for which one could resubstitute $t\leftarrow x$ if they wish to obtain $(1-\alpha)\alpha^nP_n^{*n}(x)$).
Edit: Make note of the fact that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}\ \forall r\in\mathbb{R}\backslash \{1\},\sum_{k=1}^nr^k=\frac{r-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$. Given this, assuming the $a_j$ constants follow an geometric sequence (i.e. $\exists b\in\mathbb{R}\ \mathrm{s.t.}\ \forall j\in\mathbb{N}, a_j=b^j$), the inner summation reduces to the following:
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^na_j\frac{a^j}{s{(s+a)}^j}&=\frac{1}{s}\sum_{j=1}^nb^j\frac{a^j}{{(s+a)}^j}\\
&=\frac{1}{s}\sum_{j=1}^n\left(\frac{ab}{s+a}\right)^j\\
&=\frac{1}{s}\left(\frac{\frac{ab}{s+a}-\left(\frac{ab}{s+a}\right)^{n+1}}{1-\frac{ab}{s+a}}\right)\\
&=\frac{ab}{s(s+a)}\left(\frac{1-\frac{a^nb^n}{{(s+a)}^n}}{1-\frac{ab}{s+a}}\right)\\
&=\frac{ab}{s(s+a)}\left(\frac{\frac{{(s+a)}^n-a^nb^n}{{(s+a)}^n}}{\frac{s+a-ab}{s+a}}\right)\\
&=\frac{ab}{s}\left(\frac{{(s+a)}^n-a^nb^n}{(s+a-ab){(s+a)}^n}\right)\\
&=\frac{ab{(s+a)}^n-a^{n+1}b^{n+1}}{s(s+a-ab){(s+a)}^n}
\end{align}
Given the above, the subsequent equations hold:
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}\left\{\sum_{n=0}^\infty(1-\alpha)\alpha^nP_n^{*n}(t)\right\}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(1-\alpha)\left(\alpha\frac{C_n}{s}+\alpha\frac{ab{(s+a)}^n-a^{n+1}b^{n+1}}{s(s+a-ab){(s+a)}^n}\right)^n\\
&=(1-\alpha)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{\alpha}{s}\right)^n\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}C_n^k\left(\frac{ab{(s+a)}^n-a^{n+1}b^{n+1}}{(s+a-ab){(s+a)}^n}\right)^{n-k}
\end{align}

For reasons that I hope are apparent from the above formulation, I will not be finding the function expressed in terms of $x$. Though I am doubtful as to whether the answer can be expressed more analytically given the fact that it is a series that does not match any other closed-form summations of which I am aware, I do believe that each term can be expressed analytically as a closed-form function of $x$. I will not be doing this myself for the sake of brevity.

The Laplace transform of a convolution is the product of its individual Laplace transforms. Therefore
$$\mathcal{L}p^{\ast n}=(\mathcal{L}p)^n$$
Especially if $P$ is differentiable with $P'=p$, you find
$$\mathcal{L}p(s)=\int_0^\infty e^{-su}p(u)du=\int_0^\infty e^{-su} dP(u).$$
Denote
$$F(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(1-\alpha)\alpha^nP^{\ast n}(x)$$
with derivative $F'=f$. Then it holds
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{L}f(s)
&=\int_0^\infty e^{-su}dF(u)\\
&=(1-\alpha)\sum_{n=1}^\infty\alpha^n\int_0^\infty e^{-su}dP^{\ast n}(u)\\
&=(1-\alpha)\sum_{n=1}^\infty\alpha^n\mathcal{L}p^{\ast n}(s)\\
&=(1-\alpha)\sum_{n=1}^\infty\alpha^n(\mathcal{L}p)^n(s)\\
\end{aligned}
$$
such that
$$
\begin{aligned}
(1-\alpha)+\mathcal{L}f(s)
&=(1-\alpha)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\alpha\mathcal{L}p(s)\right)^n\\
&=\frac{1-\alpha}{1-\alpha\mathcal{L}p(s)}\\
\end{aligned}
$$
Taking the inverse Laplace transform yields
$$(1-\alpha)\delta(s)+f(s)=(1-\alpha)\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{1-\alpha\mathcal{L}p}\right](s)$$
and
$$
\begin{aligned}
F(x)=F(x)-F(0)=\int_{0}^x f(s)ds
&=\int_{0}^x \left((1-\alpha)\delta(s)+f(s)\right)ds\\
&=(1-\alpha)\int_{0}^x \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{1-\alpha\mathcal{L}p}\right](s)ds
\end{aligned}$$
